# Why the pinpoint (which is a javaagent) is loaded by bootstrap class loader?

Tags: java, javaagents

I am reading the code of pinpoint about javaagent, I found a wired problem.

Commonly, the java agent should be loaded by App class loader, as it is in classpath. But I found that the pinpoint is loaded by bootstrap class loader. And I checked the pinpoint-bootstrap.jar is appended to `sun.boot.class.path`. I am interested in the black magic.

here is the code. 
https://github.com/naver/pinpoint/blob/master/bootstrap/src/main/java/com/navercorp/pinpoint/bootstrap/PinpointBootStrap.java#L45

How does pinpoint achieve that?  Maybe @emeroad is clear about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the [*Boot-Class-Path* atribute in the agent's manifest](https://github.com/naver/pinpoint/blob/master/bootstrap/pom.xml#L68). Due to this entry, the agent's jar file is added to the bootstrap loader's search path. This is done additionally to appending the agent to the system (application) class loader as it is done for any agent.

All of this is done before the agent's entry class is loaded for the first time. Due to parent first-semantics of the system class loader, the bootstrap class loader is then requested to load the agent class first what it does successfully. As a consequence, the agent main class is now loaded by the bootstrap instead of the system class loader as you observe it.

On a side note, this solution is a bit hacky. Rather, there should be a launcher agent that appends the main agent to the bootstrap loader. This way, you avoid relying on the loader hierarchy in case that some alternative VM applies a different load order.

Comment: great, It is helpful to me.

Comment: About `Rather, there should be a launcher agent that appends the main agent to the bootstrap loader`, You mean that we can create two java agent. Add the main agent to bootstrap class path in the first agent.

Comment: You create one Java agent that then invokes any launcher method of the artifact that was injected into tge boot loader.

Comment: "there should be a launcher agent that appends the main agent to the bootstrap loader". Could you expand? This is a bit difficult to understand. Nice answer!